# Making a usb wifi device work an a PowerPC Debian computer (iBook G4)

Tags: debian, wifi

I recently installed Debian Wheezy onto an old iBook g4 I bought second hand. The computer does not have a wifi card installed. After the installation, I have completely updated my software to the latest versions. However, I can't seem to make my USB WiFi device work.

Firstly, using iwconfig only returns eth0 and lo and states that ”no wireless extension found ." There is no wlan0 option. I also downloaded some drivers (firmware-realtek) after some Google searching as it appears to be the correct driver for the DigiTech device.

Is there anyway to get this to work?

**EDIT**

As requested, here is the result of lsusb and lsmod:

lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
uinput                 11283  2 
parport_pc             26474  0 
lp                     11810  0 
parport                31671  2 lp,parport_pc
radeon                768029  0 
bnep                   14558  2 
rfcomm                 35470  0 
power_supply           11815  1 radeon
bluetooth             136267  8 rfcomm,bnep
ttm                    50116  1 radeon
rfkill                 18175  3 bluetooth
drm_kms_helper         26400  1 radeon
drm                   172395  3 drm_kms_helper,ttm,radeon
binfmt_misc            10993  1 
nfsd                  213680  2 
nfs                   327153  0 
nfs_acl                 6471  2 nfs,nfsd
auth_rpcgss            36967  2 nfs,nfsd
fscache                36196  1 nfs
lockd                  66529  2 nfs,nfsd
sunrpc                178639  6 lockd,auth_rpcgss,nfs_acl,nfs,nfsd
therm_adt746x          11315  0 
snd_powermac           57147  2 
snd_pcm                65334  1 snd_powermac
snd_page_alloc          9701  1 snd_pcm
snd_seq                49320  0 
snd_seq_device          9028  1 snd_seq
snd_timer              20917  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    52909  9 snd_timer,snd_seq_device,snd_seq,snd_pcm,snd_powermac
soundcore               8882  1 snd
loop                   18579  0 
i2c_powermac            7531  0 
evdev                  13454  21 
ext4                  379254  1 
crc16                   5367  2 ext4,bluetooth
jbd2                   60959  1 ext4
mbcache                 8814  1 ext4
sg                     24836  0 
firewire_ohci          33626  0 
firewire_core          48897  1 firewire_ohci
sungem                 30943  0 
ohci_hcd               33761  0 
ehci_hcd               46130  0 
usbcore               132463  3 ehci_hcd,ohci_hcd
sungem_phy             13649  1 sungem
crc_itu_t               5387  1 firewire_core
sd_mod                 34290  3 
crc_t10dif              5368  1 sd_mod
sr_mod                 18028  0 
cdrom                  37733  1 sr_mod
usb_common              4914  1 usbcore
```

Comment: Please enhance your question with the output of `lsusb` and `lsmod`

Comment: Shaun, I've tried like 3 or 4 wireless USB adapters for my Debian 7 and they either don't work at all or glitch badly. IIRC the only readily available modern chipset for USB wifi devices among officially supported adapters on linux is Atheros9170 and even it doesn't work for me due to `wpa-supplicant` failures. See the list of Ath9k devices here: https://wiki.debian.org/carl9170. In general, situation with Wifi USB support on Linux is grim. I believe, we need a PCI card.

Comment: I'd encourage you to get the airport card for it. It works out of the box; however, that might not be ideal. As a heads up, make sure you know how to fix the GPU problem that they all suffer from.

Comment: I was able to use this usb wifi card with an iMac, I think G4, debian etch + a recompiled 2.6.29 kernel (I couldn't make it boot with a newer one). `Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n`. It's a cheap T-link one, maybe you can buy it and try. I didn't have to make any black magic to make it work. Sadly, I don't have it anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I had a feeling this was not going to be an easy fix, but I'm going to keep trying for now. I would like to just use the airport card, but the antenna is missing, as well as the metal frame to hold the card.